# UWP: ScrollViewer inside an ItemsPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to create a pivot, with a DataBinding to a List of PivotItems.
Each of these items should be surrounded by a ScrollViewer.
Unfortunately it doesn't work the way I was thinking....

My code:

MainPage:

```
<Page
x:Class="PivotSample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PivotSample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Pivot Title="Pivot" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPivotItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <UserControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

UserControl (the second UserControl is the same):

```
<UserControl
x:Class="PivotSample.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PivotSample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<StackPanel Background="Yellow">
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelMainPage : ViewModelBase
{
    private IList<PivotItem> _pivotItems;
    private PivotItem _currentPivotItem;

    public IList<PivotItem> PivotItems
    {
        get { return _pivotItems; }
        set { _pivotItems = value; }
    }

    public PivotItem CurrentPivotItem
    {
        get { return _currentPivotItem; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPivotItem));
            _currentPivotItem = value;

        }
    }
}
```

When I start the project comes following message: "The program '[2940] name.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

But when I replace the ScrollViewer with a Grid or StackPanel it will works but then I won't see all of my PivotItem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Putting a new answer, as the question has changed it's context.)

Looks like the Pivot Control screws up, if you use a list of `PivotItems`  at it'
s `ItemsSource`.

Anyway: That's not the way DataBindings are intended.

As the name suggests, you bind to **Data**, not to *controls* or *UI Elements*. `PivotItems` are UI Controls (although they are more of a logical than a visual representation) and should not be part of your ViewModel.

Just change the type in your ViewModel to some actual data (a List of String, Object, or whatever classes you create) and it works fine

Alternatively, if you want to place a fixed content inside a Pivot Control, you don't need to bind it at all and you can just place the PivotItems directly in Xaml:

```
<Pivot>
  <PivotItem Header="First Item">
    <!-- your content display here -->
  </PivotItem>
  <PivotItem Header="Secont Item">
    <!-- your content display here -->          
  </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Ok but I don't know how I could make it otherwise... 
I want create one Page with a Pivot and each PivotItem stands for one UserControl and in each UserControl I will have different Content. For Example one UserControl shows Pictures and another shows some information.

Do you have any idea how I could implement it? Maybe with an ItemControl? If yes how?

Comment: In that case just place the items in Xaml (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

(Outdated, as question was updated)

You can only set `ItemControls` as ItemsPanelTemplate and the Scrollviewer ist not an ItemsControl, but a ContentControl (it only wraps a single child and does not display multiple items).

Also, ItemsPanelTemplate is the wrong target for what you are trying to achieve: If you want to change the content of the PivotItems inside the Pivot, just set the regular `ItemTemplate`.

```
<Pivot>
  <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ScrollViewer>
        <!-- your content display here -->
      </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Just tried it, and it works perfectly. Maybe your `DefaultScrollViewer` Style breaks something.

Comment: I think I do something wrong....
`code`
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Pivot Title="Pivot" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPivotItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <PivotItem Header="{Binding Header}" Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
`code`

Comment: Yep. There is already a PivotItem in there, you don't need to put it in the Template. There you just define what is placed inside if the PivotItem.

Comment: Then just put your UserControl at where my current comment says "your content here".

Comment: And then in Visual Studio, just take a look at the live visual tree and see what's actually created. Pivots are a composition of like 6 Grids, a ScrollViewer, a PivotItemsPresenter, multiple hidden Buttons and so on. If you can't scroll then, it's most probably that your user control doesn't claim enough height.

Comment: First I tried it this way but when I bind my List of Pivotitems to the ItemSource-Property from the Pivot, the ScrollViewer doesn't work...
This is the Live-VisualTree: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=723AA7AFB3888B73!185597&authkey=!ACL52KTloBbpokU&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: And this is the xaml-Code
`<Pivot Title="Pivot" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPivotItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}">
            <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <UserControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot> `

Comment: And I don't think any Height is the reason, because the ScrollBar should be seen.

Comment: You got to look a few levels deeper. That highlighted ScrollViewer ist Part of the Pivot Control. Yours is under the PivotItemPresenter inside a PivotItem.

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem, but I don't know why no ScrollViewer in pivot element is applied... 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=723AA7AFB3888B73!185600&authkey=!AJFZ9INLms0ym6E&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: Please update your question with the complete source code.

Comment: So I edited my question. Now you will find the complete source code.